# Bootstrap navbar not fixed top for mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason, my html file will not have the navbar fixed at the top when the website is accessed through a mobile phone. It is, however, fixed at the top for my PC web browsers. What exactly is wrong here?

Note: If I remove responsive.css, then the mobile version is fixed at the top, but not responsive.
Various different answers suggested nav bar fixed top, 0 pixel padding, and user scalable no. None of those seemed to work for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <title>T6</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
      }

      .form-signin {
        max-width: 300px;
        padding: 19px 29px 29px;
        margin: 0 auto 20px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
           -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
      }
      .form-signin .form-signin-heading,
      .form-signin .checkbox {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .form-signin input[type="text"],
      .form-signin input[type="password"] {
        font-size: 16px;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        padding: 7px 9px;
      }

    </style>



  </head>


    <br><br><br>
  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="brand" href="#">TMedia</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="/Polar/about.html">About</a></li>       
              <li><a href="/Polar/login2.html">Login</a></li>
              <li><a href="/Polar/contact.html">Contact Us</a>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


 <a href="http://google.com">
<img src="google.jpg" alt="HTML tutorial" width="100" height="100"></a></p>

 <a href="http://yahoo.com">
<img src="yahoo.jpg" alt="HTML tutorial" width="100" height="100"></a></p>

 <!-- /container -->

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know this doesnt answer your technical question, but I think the reason for not fixing on a small screen is that realestate is more precious. On a large screen you can afford to dedicate the space.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor There seems to be some padding at the top despite me not putting it there. Is there anyway for me totally eliminate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, my only problem here was my version of Bootstrap.

In the above code, I was running 2.2.2 and it does not support all mobile aspects fully. After ugprading to 3.0.3, everything works fine.